# How to avoid shutdown on critical battery?

Tags: power-management

There exists a [well-known bug in gnome-power-manager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/60442), which breaks Ubuntu on computers with 2 or more batteries. If one is empty, Ubuntu will shutdown ('critical battery'). As a workaround, it can useful to disable shutdown on critical battery status. However with Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, the GUI doesn't allow this. What can I do?

Comment: I would hibernate and switch the batteries...

Comment: I also found this useful in installing a new battery.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please install dconf-editor (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) and go to

org gnome settings-daemon plugins power

Click the shutdown that is highlighted and choose "nothing" from the options as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Please do be careful. If the 2nd battery runs out of juice be sure to shutdown yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the system and dismount the empty battery. BTW, that bug **was fixed 9 years ago**. If you experience it again, **then is obviously another bug.**

Comment: This bug was discussed 9 years ago (I feel old). I'm sure whether there was a valid solution. Of course, it's possible that todays bug is unrelated with similar symptoms.