# Turn off battery control in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: power-management, battery

I own a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 11S  that suffered from battery failure when i poured coffee over the keyboard. I have checked the battery voltage manually and it is full. The computer also seem to be able to use the battery, it can sleep for extended periods without dying. However, as soon as I unplug it Ubuntu turns the computer to sleep to protect the data since the internal voltmeter seem to indicate zero charge.

How can I turn off this feature? I understand that it would mean I wouldn't be able to check the battery status, but it would be an acceptable trade off to be able to use the machine untethered.

Comment: What does _/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now_ and _/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_ say? (If you are on battery those files might be called _charge_now_ and _charge_full_)

Comment: Those files are under _/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1_ for me. energy_full: "cat: energy_full: No such device". energy_now: "0"

@bain

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/378440/how-to-avoid-shutdown-on-critical-battery